# Issues opening and reading files in C

Tags: c

I have some program that is supposed to read a filename from the command line right after the program is invoked. Then, it reads in all the data from the file, including header data, etc., which is defined as part of the following struct.

When I read in the header information from another source, it tells me that I have 29 section headers, yet when I use my own function (below) it says I have 0. I don't know whether I am opening this file incorrectly. What is going wrong here?

This is how I am opening the file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    // open the file.
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // read in the data.
    void *data = get_elf_data(fp);
}
```

This is the header struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char  identity[16];        // ELF specification information
    unsigned short nsectionheaders; // count of section headers in table
} FileHeader;
```

And here is the function that is supposed to read in the data:

```
static void *get_elf_data(FILE *fp)
{
    char ELF_IDENTITY[] = { 0x7f, 'E', 'L', 'F', ELFCLASS32, ELFDATA2LSB, EV_CURRENT};
    FileHeader hdr;
    int nread = fread(hdr.identity, 1, sizeof(ELF_IDENTITY), fp);  // read first bytes, verify proper ELF header
    if (nread < sizeof(ELF_IDENTITY) || memcmp(hdr.identity, ELF_IDENTITY, sizeof(ELF_IDENTITY)) != 0)
        return NULL; // reject if file doesn't have correct 32-bit Elf header

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp);       // get number of bytes in entire file
    rewind(fp);
    void *data = malloc(size);
    if (!data)
        return NULL;
    nread = fread(data, 1, size, fp);  // read entire file into memory
    if (nread != size) return NULL;
    printf("The number of section headers %d\n", hdr.nsectionheaders);
    return data;

}
```

The function is also not returning NULL.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to open the file in binary mode (`"rb"`)?

Comment: FileHeader.identity is declared to be a single char, but you treat it as a `char*` in the code.

Comment: Yes, but FileHeader.identity isn't an array, it is a single char... You may have intended it to be 7 chars long?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Fixing it to the above doesn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, as you don't asked for a compact struct, C compiler has misaligned the fields in the header.

Perhaps you had better to read them character per character, to build the header fields in an architecture independient mode.  normally, if you have a four byte integer and you declare a char, followed by a short, you'll get  the short padded to 16bit boundary, leaving a hole in your structure (a hole of one byte).

you can use your C compiler to get the fields properly aligned in some packed structure, but the details of doing this are compiler dependent.

in gcc, it can be done with something as: (borrowed from the manual)

```
      struct my_unpacked_struct
       {
          char c;
          int i;
       };

      struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) my_packed_struct
        {
           char c;
           int  i;
           struct my_unpacked_struct s;
        };
```

but your compiler can do it another way.

NOTE: fields will get this way this alignment (on x86 intel):

```
    offset  field
    ======  =====
    0       [my_packed_struct.c]
    1       [my_packed_struct.i.lsb]
    5       [my_packed_struct.s.c]
    9       [my_packed_struct.s.i.lsb]
    13      [end]
```

I have to say this is a complex example as you have put a misaligned unpacked structure in the middle of a packed one.

BR

Comment: The structure in the question has 16 bytes followed by a short. Surely that will be compactly aligned anyway?

Comment: Probably the compiler is reserving 20 bytes for it (16 for the first array, and two more pad bytes at the end to fill in a 5x32 bits ---for arrays to get aligned)  I suggest you to try print a sizeof(struct FileHeader)

Comment: You also have a library to deal with ELF data.  see ld(1) info doc  and BFD library information.

Comment: No, the compiler is not reserving 20 bytes. I suggest you try it yourself. The struct contains only `char` and `short` so the alignment need only match `short` (2 bytes, not 4).

Answer (score 0):

You only ever read the ELF_IDENTITY into the `hdr`:

```
    int nread = fread(hdr.identity, 1, sizeof(ELF_IDENTITY), fp);  // read first bytes, verify proper ELF header
```

You need to read the rest of the header into this structure, before you can reliably use the `nsectionheaders` field.

The fix should be simple enough: change `sizeof(ELF_IDENTITY)` above to `sizeof(hdr)`

Comment: yes, but `*data` is not `hdr`. The `nsectionheaders` field is in `hdr`.

Comment: How would I know how much to read in if the header size is not specified?

Comment: I have edited the answer. You should read at least as much of the header as you actually use.

Comment: One more question though - changing the sizeof won't explicitly store the nsectionheaders into the struct field, though right? I'd probably need a different fread to do that.

Comment: I had assumed that your FileHeader structure actually matched the ELF header structure. I see now that it does not. So yes, changing the size of the read does not work. You need to read the ELF header, then use it to locate the section header. Find the number of sections within that.

Comment: No, it actually does, I just eliminated some of the extra bits for readability. Not sure why it would automatically work though even if they are the same.

Comment: Most people tackling this would define FileHeader to actually match the ELF header structure :) This would be a good start for you too, I think.

Comment: "No, it actually does" - not according to the link posted by Klas Lindbäck!

Comment: It's a custom ELF header defined for a different purpose. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: In that case - "changing the sizeof won't explicitly store the nsectionheaders into the struct field, though right?" - fread will read the number of bytes specified from the file. If you specify the size of the structure, you read into the whole structure, including the `nsectionheaders` field.

Comment: Great. I didn't know that it "knew" enough to be able to store in the right place dynamically.

Comment: There's no special knowledge required. The layout of the FileHeader struct matches the structure in storage, right? The `fread` just copies bytes, nothing more, nothing less. By the way the first parameter to fread should really be `&hdr` rather than `hdr.identity`, though it's not likely to break anything as is.

Comment: You need to be aware that the location of nsectionheaders is different for 32- and 64-bit ELFs.